# Magento Controller forward in admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, adminhtml

I'm creating simple Magento module based on [this article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table).
I have a problem with my admin **New Item** action.

```
<?php

class Namespace_Gallery_Adminhtml_GalleryController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
protected function _initAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('namespace/gallery');

    return $this;
}

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_initAction();
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('gallery/adminhtml_gallery'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function editAction()
{
    echo 'edit';
}

public function newAction()
{
    $this->_forward('edit');
}
```

Items indexAction works and displays my items, when I click on any item it returns 'edit' as intended. Unfortunately clicking "Add new item" gives 404 (url is good).

Any ideas?

Comment: Wait, are you seeing "404" displayed in the content area of an admin page, or are you actually receiving a 404 response header? The former is an indication that ACL for that resource is borked.

Comment: looks like the mystery located in your statement: `url is good`. How do you generate / create the url for newAction?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add adminhtml layout update xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <[module]_adminhtml_[controller]_index>
        <reference name="content">
                <block type="[module]/adminhtml_[frontname]" name="[module]_grid"/>
        </reference>
    </[module]_adminhtml_[controller]_index>
</layout>
```

And of course it needs to be set in config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <[module]>
                <file>[module].xml</file>
            </[module]>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

And you may need to load/render layout in editAction()

Comment: editAction() and indexAction() works great. There is a problem with newAction() (as I mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you call your requested custom action you may have to add something to your config.xml

Assuming that this is what you call:
http(s)://yourdomain.com/index.php/gallery/admin_gallery/new

then add the following to your config.xml inside the `<admin><routers>`-node

```
<gallery>
    <use>admin</use>
    <args>
        <module>Namespace_Gallery</module>
        <frontName>gallery</gallery>
    </args>
</gallery>
```